# How to get the data from Redis cache based on the matcher of the hashKey using spring framework redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have created a cache data with below sample data and am using put operation:

```
void put(H key, HK hashKey, HV value);
```

here h refers to postId which is randomly genearted, HK refers to combination of streetId and StreetCode delimited by underscore and HV refers to person details dto object

cache data:

```
hashOperations.put(randomkey1,"street1_code1",p1)
hashOperations.put(randomkey2,"street2_code1",p2)
hashOperations.put(randomkey3,"street1_code2",p3)
```

I need to retrieve the specific information of all the data based on the providing HK **streetCode** .
For example when I retrieve the streetCode like  **"code1"**, only get the related information data from cache

Here I am using springboot starter redis dependency and redis connections are configured in yml file. By using auotwired of org.springframework.data.redis.core.HashOperations doing the operations in my application